# ngx_str_set truncating value

Tags: c, nginx

Within an nginx C module I have the following code :

```
static void
append_user_id(ngx_http_request_t *r, ngx_str_t *user_id)
{
  ngx_table_elt_t *h;
  h = ngx_list_push(&r->headers_in.headers);
  h->hash = 1;
  ngx_str_set(&h->key, "X-User-Id");
  h->value = *user_id;
}
```

which is attempting to add a header key,value pair before passing upstream. For some reason the value on the newly added header appears to be getting truncated to 7 chars. Printing `user_id` out to the log shows that it does indeed contain something much longer than 7 chars however the value on the resulting header being sent upstream is always truncated.

Can anyone see why and suggest a fix please. 
Tks

**EDIT** : This is on nginx 1.6.1 and it's always truncated to 7 chars.

Comment: How are you printing `h->value`?

Comment: via `ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_ERR, r->connection->log,0, user_id.data);` directly before the function call `append_user_id(r, &user_id);`

Answer (score 0):

By definition ngx_str_t has both, data and the length in it:

```
typedef struct {
    size_t      len;
    u_char     *data;
} ngx_str_t;

ngx_str_t user_id;
```

Problem is that whenever you use the macro `ngx_str_set(&user_id, x)`, all it does is:

```
#define ngx_str_set(str, text)
        \(str)->len = sizeof(text) - 1; (str)->data = (u_char *) text
```

Basically, it just assigns `user_id.data` to the text you pass in 
and sets `user_id.len` to `sizeof(text)-1`. So as long as text is a constant string, `sizeof(text)` comes out correctly to be the length
of the constant string you pass in e.g.

`ngx_str_set(&user_id, "Some User Name");`

will correctly set: `user_id.len = sizeof("Some User Name") - 1; // = 14`

But if you have some dynamic allocated memory (or you have a pointer to a memory location), sizeof(text)-1 just returns the size of pointer - 1 (which is 7). e.g.:

```
const char *x = "Some User Name";
ngx_str_set(&user_id, x);    // len field will be 7 not 14 as sizeof(x)-1 is 8-1=7
```

Any function that does not refer to the `len` field, will work correctly e.g. if you call `ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_ERR, r->connection->log,0, user_id.data);`, will work fine as you are only passing `user_id.data`. But any function that uses `ngx_str_t` such as `r->headers_in.headers`, will look at the `len` field, which has 7 written in it and it will only use 7 characters out of the data.

In this particular code you have pasted, you will have to go back to the place where `user_id` variable was set.

Possible Solution:

a) set len field yourself

```
some_value.len = ngx_strlen(x);
some_value.data = x;
```

b) if you want to copy data, then:

```
some_value.len = ngx_strlen(x);
some_value.data = ngx_pstrdup(r->connection->pool, x);
```